# How to extract range of characters from a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

If I have a string such as the following:

```
 String myString = "SET(someRandomName, \"hi\", u)";
```

where I know that `"SET("` will always exists in the string, but the length of `"someRandomName"` is unknown, how would I go about deleting all the characters from `"("` to the first instance of `"""`? So to re-iterate, I would like to delete this substring: `"SET(someRandomName, \""` from `myString`.

How would I do this in C#.Net?

EDIT: I don't want to use regex for this.

Comment: Time to learn Regular Expressions.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty easily googled problem.  And why don't you want to use regex?

Comment: I have googled around actually, the only thing i could find was replacing it from a known index to another known index... but since i won't know the length of someRandomName ... it's hard to know what the end index would be...

Comment: The syntax above isn't even valid.

Comment: @Joey it's not about the syntax.. it's about me having a string that will look very similar to that... your comment is so unhelpful....

Comment: You know, for something that's rather straightforward to implement (using either regex or just browing through the docs of `string` methods) your question is remarkably unhelpful, too ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Providing the string will *always* have this structure, the easiest is to use [`String.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) to look-up the index of the first occurence of `"`. [`String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0) then gives you appropriate portion of the original string.

Likewise you can use [`String.LastIndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3.aspx) to find the index of the first `"` from the *end* of the string. Then you will be able to extract just the value of the second argument (`"hi"` in your sample).

You will end up with something like this:

```
int begin = myString.IndexOf('"');
int end = myString.LastIndexOf('"');
string secondArg = myString.Substring(begin, end - begin + 1);
```

This will yield `"\"hi\""` in `secondArg`.

**UPDATE**: To remove a portion of the string, use the [`String.Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx) method:

```
int begin = myString.IndexOf('(');
int end = myString.IndexOf('"');
string altered = myString.Remove(begin + 1, end - begin - 1);
```

This will yield `"SET(\"hi\", u)"` in `altered`.

Comment: I just noticed your original goal was to *delete* a portion of the original string *from* it. However, you can achieve it with the tools mentioned in my answer anyway which you, most likely, already did. Updated my answer accordingly for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been years, but .Net been has also evolved in the meantime.
Consider using range operator in case anyone looking here for an answer.
Assuming that `Set(` and `\"hi\", u)` is constant value (8 digit without the escapes):

```
var sub = myString[^4...^8];
myString.Replace(sub, replaceValue);
```

more examples and a good explanation in this [article](http://humbletoolsmith.com/2019/12/21/csharp-strings-with-ranges,-and-indexes/) or of course in microsoft docs

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to transform

```
SET(someRandomName, "hi", u)
```

into:

```
SET(u)
```

To achieve that, you can use:

```
String newString = "SET(" + myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf(',') + 1).Trim();
```

To explain this bit by bit:

```
myString.LastIndexOf(',')
```

will give you the index (position) of your last `,` character. Increment it by 1 to get the start index of the third argument in your `SET` function.

```
myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf(',') + 1)
```

The `Substring` method will eliminate all characters up to the specified position. In this case, we’re eliminating everything up to (and including) the last `,`. In the example above, this would eliminate the `SET(someRandomName, "hi",` part, and leave us with `u)`.

The `Trim` is necessary simply to remove the leading space character before your `u`.

Finally, we prepend `SET(` to our substring (since we had formerly removed it due to our `Substring`).

**Edit**: Based on your comment below <strike>(which contradicts what you asked in your question)</strike>, you can use:

```
String newString = "SET(" + myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(',') + 1).Trim();
```

Comment: i don't want SET(u) ... i want SET("hi", u) to be my resulting value.. thanks anyways

Comment: @BlueMonster - Replace `LastIndexOf` with `IndexOf`

Comment: You should try to use proper syntax when asking questions; it’s really unclear what `"""` (an invalid string literal in C#) is intended to meant. It might actually have been more helpful to just use `"`. (The proper string literal is `"\""`.)

Comment: what """ was meant to mean is that i want the first instance where " occurs.... i thought that was the clearest way of putting it as it is part of the string...

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty awful, but this will accomplish what you want with a simple linq statement. Just presenting as an alternative to the `IndexOf` answers.

```
string myString = "SET(someRandomName, \"hi\", 0)";
string fixedStr = new String( myString.ToCharArray().Take( 4 ).Concat( myString.ToCharArray().SkipWhile( c => c != '"' ) ).ToArray() );
```

yields: SET("hi", 0)

Note: the skip is hard-coded for 4 characters, you could alter it to skip over the characters in an array that contains them instead.